# AzureAD B2C Passwordless Template

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement the passwordless configuration as per the following custom policy:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email

I get the following error message when uploading the xml file:

B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions_passwordless" of tenant "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" makes a reference to TechnicalProfile with id "LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" but neither the policy nor any of its base policies contain such an element.Policy

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You have not deployed the Azure AD B2C starter pack.
Follow the pre requisites
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#prerequisites